# In Typst, is it possible to check if this is the "main" file?

Tags: typst

In a Typst project of multiple files, it can be easiest to only compile the file presently in focus.

While working on macro and template files, it would be nice to show some test/debug calls in the resulting document, but only if those files are being compiled directly, i.e. not `#include`'ed by other files.

This is similar to the python feature `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the intended solution is to use `#import` instead. The point of importing is specifically to access the functions and variables of a file without rendering the content. For example:

```
// macros.typ
#let diameter(r) = {2*r}
DEBUG: Radius 2 is diameter #diameter(2)
```

and then

```
// main.typ
#include "macros.typ": *
This is the main text.
```